# libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r

while installing DirichletMultinomial, in r studio found this error:-

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DirichletMultinomial’ in
>   dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
>   '/home/hpi7/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-DirichletMultinomial/00new/DirichletMultinomial/libs/DirichletMultinomial.so':
>   libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory Error: loading failed

Answer (score 2):

Depending of the OS you are using, you will need first to install the library GNU Scientific Library (GSL) (the development package).

On my Linux Mint machine, it is:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

Then, you can install the package:

```r
BiocManager::install("DirichletMultinomial")
```