# cannot install custom library in R

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to install a custom package that I worked on for a while after moving them to a new system. I am getting the following error.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘propSignals’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/boniface/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-propSignals/00new/propSignals/libs/propSignals.so':
  /home/boniface/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-propSignals/00new/propSignals/libs/propSignals.so: undefined symbol: _Z15do_linear_decayN4Rcpp6VectorILi14ENS_15PreserveStorageEEEii
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/boniface/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/propSignals’
```

I tried the following approaches and they didnt work:

1. [R: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943764/r-error-in-dyn-loadfile-dllpath-dllpath)
2. [libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797296/libgsl-so-25-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

More information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.2 usethis_2.0.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.1    pkgload_1.2.2     R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.11      fastmap_1.1.0     fansi_0.5.0      
 [8] tools_3.6.3       pkgbuild_1.2.0    sessioninfo_1.1.1 utf8_1.2.2        cli_3.0.1         withr_2.4.2       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[15] remotes_2.4.1     rprojroot_2.0.2   tibble_3.1.5      lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.4.1      processx_3.5.2    purrr_0.3.4      
[22] callr_3.7.0       vctrs_0.3.8       fs_1.5.0          ps_1.6.0          testthat_3.0.4    memoise_2.0.0     glue_1.4.2       
[29] cachem_1.0.6      pillar_1.6.3      compiler_3.6.3    desc_1.4.0        prettyunits_1.1.1 pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

What should I do? I spent so much time trying to fix this and it didnt go anywhere. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Maybe the issue is caused by the fact you are using a very outdated R version? The current one is 4.1.1 while you are using the 3.6.3 one!

Comment: @PaulSmith, I found out that one of the file was updated and it was not compiling. I am going to investigate that first.